# Сравнить элемет списка с предыдущим

Tags: kotlin

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)

for(i in 0..array.lastIndex-1)
{
    println("${array[i]} compare ${array[i+1]}")
}
```

Есть ли эквивалентный метод в коллекциях kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iterable.zipWithNext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html), для Array использовать так:

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)

array.toList().zipWithNext { a, b -> 
    println("$a compare $b")
}

array.asIterable().zipWithNext { a, b -> 
    println("$a compare $b")
}

val zipSum = array.asIterable().zipWithNext { a, b -> 
    a + b
}
```